# How to use venice/nomad at http://nomad-cli.com/

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, cocoapods

I'm a new iOS developer.
I've found some useful site. http://nomad-cli.com/
But don't know how to use it.

I want to use 'venice' in-app verification.
It shows $ iap verify /path/to/receipt for simple description.

I have tried these
  1. 
 at terminal application

> -$ gem install venice

1. at podfile

> require 'venice'
>   data = "(Base64-Encoded Receipt Data)"
>   if receipt
>   = Venice::Receipt.verify(data)
>   p receipt.to_h
>   end
>   
>   Condition:

xcode 5.1.1
OSX 10.9.4

Can I use this for verification of in-app purchase receipt when iPhone users buy something in my app?
 If so, how can I use this?
  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use Parse SDK (http://parse.com). Their SDK handles in-app purchases with receipt verification, and it's really easy to set it up. Examples from their docs:

```
// "Listen" for each purchase that can be made in the app
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:@"Pro" block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
    // Write business logic that should run once this product is purchased.
    isPro = YES;
}];

// Perform the purchase
[PFPurchase buyProduct:@"Pro" block:^(NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // Run UI logic that informs user the product has been purchased, such as displaying an alert view.
    }
}];
```